# Apache Spark: Save results to a database

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming

I am currently trying out Spark streaming. I have been able to obtain the required results, but now I am just doing a print to the terminal terminal like :

```
myResults.print()
```

Which prints the results to the terminal.

What I am trying to achieve is an architecture similar to [this](http://thenewstack.io/apache-kafka-spark-database-real-time-trinity/).

Is there any way to write these results to a table in a database.
How can I do this and which database I should use ?

Answer (score 0):

**Which database I should use??**

Well this completely depends on your requirement on what you want to do with the data, once it is persisted on to the disk. You can choose any database which suits your need, from Mysql, Oracle, MongoDB etc. Or you can save it to the Hadoop File System.

**How Can I do this??**

You can use the Spark Map function to iterate through all the data and insert into your choice of database. Like

```
    statuses.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(String s) throws Exception {
            //You Code to parse the String and insert into the database of your choice.
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks your reply.I am using scala and ı have already choice Cassandra.But when  i run this code ,i am getting error.Can  you look at  ?    scala> val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("cat", 30), ("fox", 40)))
collection: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[6] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> collection.saveToCassandra("test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count")) error: value saveToCassandra is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]

Comment: I think my commend was fixed.If you want i can write another question ?

Comment: Spark distribution does not come in built with saveToCassandra.          I think you are missing the Spark Cassandra connector library. Start the spark shell with the package including Cassandra connector. like shown in this link.http://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.

Comment: Why are you using the "map" function? You are not mapping anything here, but performing an operation on the data?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this

Use the [foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#foreachPartition(scala.Function1)) and write a [VoidFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/VoidFunction.html) that saves to your chosen data source.

> which database I should use ?

What do you have in play? What do you intend to do with the data? How long is a piece of string?